# can we have many to many equivalent of nested sets ? graph database?

Tags: database, symfony, graph, doctrine-orm, nested-sets

In my application, I am dealing with recipes.

Any recipe can contain multiple recipes. And any recipe can be included inside any other recipe. It's very dynamic.

So far, I could not use a nested set like I would do for folders cause it's not handling many to many relationships (at least doctrine tree does not).

Is there something allowing that with SQL ? with Doctrine ? Do I need a graph database ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Do you need a nested set per se?  Perhaps a normal self referencing table is enough for you. You can describe a tree with that:  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing  It also works with many-to-many - a "graph" of recipes

Comment: That's what I'm doing for the moment but I need a tree because there can be infinite levels of nesting. Some times I'm doing analytics on my recipes : raw material cost calculations. So far I'm loading an array of objets (recipes) and looping though their children, which is costly in terms of performances

Comment: It's simple to do relationally and in SQL, just make a relation / table `contained_in (containing_recipe_id, contained_recipe_id)`.

Comment: you couldn't be less specific :p Can you elaborate ? How can I query an entire tree with this, bothsides (through parents and through children) ?